# To get the transpose of the table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I am having this attendance table:

```
days     emp1    emp2    emp3    emp4
1        P       P       A       P
2        P       P       P       P
3        P       A       P       L
4        A       P       P       A
```

and I want to transpose this in Oracle. I want an output like this:

```
     1 2 3 4
emp1 P P P A
emp2 P P A P
emp3 A P P P
emp4 P P L A
```

Comment: you could make use of `unpivot` for emp1,2,3,4 then `pivot` the days

Comment: Refer http://oracletuts.net/tutorials/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql/

Comment: thankx for replying.....can you please show me the query

Comment: Your design for the `attendance` table is wrong - you should normalize this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do what you wanted with a pivot operator (the unpivot looked too complex to achieve it more easily):

```
with w as
(
  select * from 
  (
    select t.days, t.emp1, t.emp2, t.emp3, t.emp4
    from my_table t
  )
  pivot (max(emp1) emp1, max(emp2) emp2, max(emp3) emp3, max(emp4) emp4 for (days) in (1 as a1, 2 as a2, 3 as a3, 4 as a4))
)
select w.a1_emp1 d1, w.a2_emp1 d2, w.a1_emp1 d3, w.a1_emp1 d4 from w
union all
select w.a1_emp2 d1, w.a2_emp2 d2, w.a3_emp2 d3, w.a4_emp2 d4 from w
union all
select w.a1_emp3 d1, w.a2_emp3 d2, w.a3_emp3 d3, w.a4_emp3 d4 from w
union all
select w.a1_emp4 d1, w.a2_emp4 d2, w.a3_emp4 d3, w.a4_emp4 d4 from w
;
```

You get:

```
D1  D2  D3  D4
P   P   P   P
P   P   A   P
A   P   P   P
P   P   L   A
```